# Coldfusion Stored Procedure error

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, coldfusion-7

CF: Version 7.02

Platform: Windows

DB: MySQL 5.1.45-community

I'm getting an error when executing a simple Stored Procedure in CF.

```
<CFSTOREDPROC DATASOURCE="datasource" PROCEDURE="deletePosition"> 
     <CFPROCPARAM CFSQLTYPE="cf_sql_integer" DBVARNAME="varID" VALUE="#varID#"> 
</CFSTOREDPROC>
```

Stored Procedure:

```
   DROP PROCEDURE deletePosition 
   CREATE DEFINER= PROCEDURE deletePosition(in varID int) 
   BEGIN 
        UPDATE positions SET pos_active = 0 WHERE pos_id = varID; 
        UPDATE tour SET tour_active = 0 WHERE pos_id = varID; 
   END
```

`VarID` is being passed in and this is the error that it's generating:

```
Error Executing Database Query.

Parameter index of 2 is out of range (1, 1)
SQL   {call deletePosition( (param 1) , (param 2) )}
SQLSTATE      S1009
```

According to my network guy, the drives are close to being up to date.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your entire Stored Procedure?

Comment: That SQLSTATE value (S1009) is associated with a boatload of MySQL errors. Absent a stored procedure definition, and the SQL statement that is being submitted to MySQL, it's not possible to debug this problem. (Under the heading "Stored Procedure:", you show two UPDATE statements; this is not a MySQL stored procedure. You say that "VarID is being passed in", but there is no demonstration of how this is being accomplished. The SQL reflected in the error message does not appear to be valid, if that is the actual statement being submitted to MySQL, because `(param 1)` and `(param 2)` are invalid.

Comment: Also, post the ColdFusion code that calls the SP.

Comment: DROP PROCEDURE `deletePosition`
        CREATE DEFINER= PROCEDURE `deletePosition`(in varID int)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE positions SET pos_active  = 0 WHERE pos_id = varID;
    
            UPDATE tour SET tour_active = 0 WHERE pos_id = varID;
        END

Comment: <CFSTOREDPROC DATASOURCE="datasource" PROCEDURE="deletePosition"> 
<CFPROCPARAM CFSQLTYPE="cf_sql_integer" DBVARNAME="varID" VALUE="#varID#"> 
</CFSTOREDPROC>

Comment: There is the full stored procedure and then the CF code that calls it. Thanks!

Comment: It's probably not relevent, but cfstoredproc no longer supports named parameters.  That means the dbvarname attribute is at best, unnecessary, and at worst, causing the problem.  Just for fun, take it out.

Comment: @DanBracuk Doesn't CF7 still support that? I did kill it and I got the same result! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your SQL, it looks like you only have a single varID?  Does your SP accept 1 parameter or 2?  If just one, then this should work:

```
call deletePosition (1)
```

I haven't used Cold Fusion in a while, but this is one way I remember calling SPs:

```
<CFQUERY dataSource="datasource">
deletePosition #varID#
</CFQUERY>
```

Does that work?

Comment: Only one variable. I just posted the actually SP above. Thanks

Comment: Also, I can go in say via PHPmyadmin and call the procedure like the example listed above posting in the variable # of the position I want to delete and it works just fine but when called via CF it throws an error.

Comment: What is the value of varId?  Also, I've edited my answer for to give you something to try.

Comment: Funny thing is, THAT works. I had planned that as a workaround and you also came to the same conclusion. So, unless a solution can be found I will do that. Problem is, the developer who wrote the code before me gets a varable called strQuerystatus which if it is 200 then it will proceed as normal. I don't know of a way to get a qryStatus from <cfquery>. I would more likely have to write a try catch block and unless there is a SQL exception then status gets assigned a value of 200 if not and there is an error it gets assigned a value of 300. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @weggie -- I haven't used CF in a while but I guess you could return a value from your SP -- SELECT 1 as QueryStatus -- then add a Name attribute to your CFQuery -- then you should be able to use that variable on the page.  Again though, it's been a while :)  Hope this helped a little!  Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I do have a plan to go forward but I still want to know why this isn't working. Thanks again for taking time to answer.

Comment: @weggie -- no problem in the least -- hope you figure it out :)